# Using scp for local to remote transfer results in local to local transfer

Tags: centos, scp

I am currently using the following command to copy a local file to a remote server:

```
scp -r -P22234 -v /backup/mysql/mysql-backup.sql.gz backup@linuxweb2.co.uk:/home/backup/
```

However the file always ends up on the local server in the location I specified for the remote server.

The debug info I have is as follows:

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host linuxweb2.co.uk, user backup, command scp -v -r -t /home/backup/
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to linuxweb2.co.uk [192.168.1.1] port 22234.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '[linuxweb2.co.uk]:22234' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
backup@linuxweb2.co.uk's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -r -t /home/backup/
Sending file modes: C0644 142828 mysql-backup.sql.gz
Sink: C0644 142828 mysql-backup.sql.gz
mysql-backup.sql.gz                                                   100%  139KB 139.5KB/s   00:00
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 144640, received 2136 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 4007293.3, received 59178.5
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Comment: Looks like a successful transfer. Now where did you forward your connection to?

Comment: Forgive me, how do you mean 'forward you connection'? The server I'm transferring from is called linuxweb1, the remote server is linuxweb2. The file seems to transfer correctly but the physical file ends up back on linuxweb1 in the location I was specified with nothing copying to linuxweb2

Comment: Is `192.168.1.1` the correct IP for `linuxweb2.co.uk`?  Are you sure you don't have a DNS issue?  If you ssh to that host instead of scp do you end up in the right place?

Comment: You connected to port 22234, which is not a standard port. So you've made some (quite possibly ill-advised) alterations to your ssh configuration.

Comment: @Zoredache it appears the DNS may have been causing me an issue due to a recent domain move - thank you :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton I originally changed the port after following the Securing SSH guide on the CentOS wiki. Is that not the best thing to do?